# Como Cambiar el Radio del Borde de mi navbar al pasar el mouse

Tags: html, bootstrap

tengo un problema, actualmente estoy usando bootstrap y navbar, el boot strap lo llamo de esta manera:

```
 <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
```

el codigo de navbar es el siguiente:

```
<nav class="colorlib-nav" role="navigation" >
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default " style="position: fixed;background-color: #ff3333;margin: 25% 0px 0px 95.5%; border-radius: 40px">
       <ul class="nav justify-content">
       <li><a href="grafi_index_2.php"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-signal' style="font-size: 20px"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="registro3.php"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt' style="font-size: 20px"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="grafi_index_2.php"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-envelope' style="font-size: 20px"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="registro3.php"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-glass' style="font-size: 20px"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
 </nav>
```

aca estoy poniendo los bordes en curva, como se puede ver en la imagen siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando paso el puntero del mouse me sale de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
como haria para que el puntero de mouse que seleeciono me salga de manera curvilinea del mismo tamaño de radio que le puse borde del navbar?

Answer (score 0):

https://mdbootstrap.com/css/hover-effects/

Buenas; usando la clase hover de bootstrap podras hacer el cambio sin mucho mas, para que lo compendas mejor te dejo ejemplos en el enlace mas arriba

o usando css puro

```
a:hover { 
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo lo que necesitas, espero te sirva:

```css
li a:hover{
  background:none !important;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
 <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

<nav class="colorlib-nav" role="navigation" >
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default " style="position: fixed;background-color: #ff3333;margin: 2% 0px 0px 15.5%; border-radius: 40px">
       <ul class="nav justify-content">
       <li><a href="grafi_index_2.php"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-signal' style="font-size: 20px"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="registro3.php"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt' style="font-size: 20px"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="grafi_index_2.php"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-envelope' style="font-size: 20px"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="registro3.php"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-glass' style="font-size: 20px"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
 </nav>
```